# Solr Autocomplete: Multiple dictionarys with field and file dictionary

Tags: dictionary, solr, autocomplete, tomcat7, autosuggest

I´m trying to build an solr suggester with a solr 4.6.0 and an tomcat7. The suggester should use multiple fields from the solr(suName,suFea) and a file based dictionary(suList). The suggest with multiple fields is working. But the combination from field and a file dictionary doesn,t work because the analyzer needs the same type from every dictionary. I tried to fix the issue with multiple components. The result was an nullpointer.

Is there any option to build such a situation?

Thanks.

solrconfig.xml:

```
    <searchComponent name="suggest" class="solr.SpellCheckComponent">
  <lst name="spellchecker">
    <str name="name">suFea</str>
    <str name="classname">org.apache.solr.spelling.suggest.Suggester</str>
    <str name="lookupImpl">org.apache.solr.spelling.suggest.fst.WFSTLookupFactory</str>
    <str name="suggestAnalyzerFieldType">lowercase</str>
    <str name="field">features</str>
    <str name="buildOnCommit">true</str>
  </lst>
  <lst name="spellchecker">
    <str name="name">suName</str>
    <str name="classname">org.apache.solr.spelling.suggest.Suggester</str>
    <str name="lookupImpl">org.apache.solr.spelling.suggest.fst.WFSTLookupFactory</str>
    <str name="suggestAnalyzerFieldType">lowercase</str>
    <str name="field">name</str>
    <!--<float name="threshold">0.005</float>-->
    <str name="buildOnCommit">true</str>
  </lst>
</searchComponent>
<searchComponent name="fileSuggest" class="solr.SpellCheckComponent">  
   <lst name="spellchecker">
    <str name="name">suList</str>
    <str name="classname">org.apache.solr.spelling.suggest.Suggester</str>
    <str name="lookupImpl">org.apache.solr.spelling.suggest.fst.WFSTLookupFactory</str>
    <str name="suggestAnalyzerFieldType">lowercase</str>
    <str name="sourceLocation">./suggester/dict.txt</str>
    <str name="fieldType">string</str>
    <!--<float name="threshold">0.005</float>-->
    <str name="buildOnCommit">true</str>
  </lst>
</searchComponent>

<requestHandler name="/suggest" class="solr.SearchHandler">
  <lst name="defaults">
    <str name="echoParams">explicit</str>
    <str name="spellcheck">true</str>
    <str name="spellcheck.dictionary">suName</str>
    <str name="spellcheck.dictionary">suFea</str>
    <str name="spellcheck.dictionary">suList</str>
    <str name="spellcheck.onlyMorePopular">true</str>
    <str name="spellcheck.collate">false</str>
    <str name="spellcheck.count">25</str>
  </lst>
  <arr name="components" >
    <str>suggest</str>
    <str>fileSuggest</str>
  </arr>
</requestHandler>
```

Error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException at org.apache.solr.spelling.ConjunctionSolrSpellChecker.addChecker(ConjunctionSolrSpellChecker.java:58) at
org.apache.solr.handler.component.SpellCheckComponent.getSpellChecker(SpellCheckComponent.java:505) at
org.apache.solr.handler.component.SpellCheckComponent.prepare(SpellCheckComponent.java:123) at 
org.apache.solr.handler.component.SearchHandler.handleRequestBody(SearchHandler.java:187) at 
org.apache.solr.handler.RequestHandlerBase.handleRequest(RequestHandlerBase.java:135) at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.execute(SolrCore.java:1859) at 
org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.execute(SolrDispatchFilter.java:710) at 
org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:413) at 
org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:197) at 
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241) at 
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208) at 
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220) at 
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122) at 
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170) at
org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103) at 
org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:956) at 
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116) at
org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:423) at 
org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1079) at 
org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:625) at 
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316) at 
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) at 
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) at 
org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Answer (score 1):

i am using solr 6.2.0 version

and clearly multiple suggester work for me solrconfig.xml config as follow and managed-schema.xml config below it. if u want i can share java code here too

************************** solrconfig.xml CONFIG **************************

```
<searchComponent class="solr.SuggestComponent" name="suggest">
<lst name="suggester">
<str name="name">ilsuggester</str>
<str name="lookupImpl">FuzzyLookupFactory</str>
<str name="dictionaryImpl">DocumentDictionaryFactory</str>
<str name="field">IL_ADI</str>  
<str name="suggestAnalyzerFieldType">textgen</str>
<str name="storeDir">suggest_fuzzy_doc_expr_dict</str>
<str name="buildOnStartup">false</str>
<str name="buildOnCommit">false</str>
</lst>

<lst name="suggester">
<str name="name">ilcesuggester</str>
<str name="lookupImpl">FuzzyLookupFactory</str>
<str name="dictionaryImpl">DocumentDictionaryFactory</str>
<str name="field">ILCE_ADI</str>
<str name="suggestAnalyzerFieldType">textgen</str>
<str name="indexPath">suggestions/ilcesuggester</str>
<str name="storeDir">suggest_fuzzy_doc_expr_dict</str>
<str name="buildOnStartup">false</str>
<str name="buildOnCommit">false</str>
</lst>

<lst name="suggester">
<str name="name">mahallesuggester</str>
<str name="lookupImpl">FuzzyLookupFactory</str>
<str name="dictionaryImpl">DocumentDictionaryFactory</str>
<str name="field">MAHALLE_ADI</str>
<str name="suggestAnalyzerFieldType">textgen</str>
<str name="indexPath">suggestions/mahallesuggester</str>
<str name="storeDir">suggest_fuzzy_doc_expr_dict</str>
<str name="preserveSep">true</str>
<str name="preservePositionIncrements">true</str>
<str name="exactMatchFirst">true</str> 
<float name="threshold">0.005</float> 
<str name="buildOnStartup">false</str>
<str name="buildOnCommit">false</str>

</lst>

<lst name="suggester">
<str name="name">sokaksuggester</str>
<str name="lookupImpl">FuzzyLookupFactory</str>
<str name="dictionaryImpl">DocumentDictionaryFactory</str>
<str name="field">SOKAK</str>
<str name="suggestAnalyzerFieldType">textgen</str>
<str name="indexPath">suggestions/sokaksuggester</str>
<str name="storeDir">suggest_fuzzy_doc_expr_dict</str>
<str name="preserveSep">true</str>
<str name="preservePositionIncrements">true</str>
<str name="buildOnStartup">false</str>
<str name="buildOnCommit">false</str>
</lst>

<lst name="suggester">
<str name="name">caddesuggester</str>
<str name="lookupImpl">FuzzyLookupFactory</str>
<str name="dictionaryImpl">DocumentDictionaryFactory</str>
<str name="field">CADDE</str>
<str name="suggestAnalyzerFieldType">textgen</str>
<str name="indexPath">suggestions/caddesuggester</str>
<str name="storeDir">suggest_fuzzy_doc_expr_dict</str>
<str name="preserveSep">true</str>
<str name="preservePositionIncrements">true</str>
<str name="buildOnStartup">false</str>
<str name="buildOnCommit">false</str>
</lst>

<lst name="suggester">
<str name="name">yolsuggester</str>
<str name="lookupImpl">FuzzyLookupFactory</str>
<str name="dictionaryImpl">DocumentDictionaryFactory</str>
<str name="field">YOL_ADI</str>
<str name="suggestAnalyzerFieldType">textgen</str>
<str name="indexPath">suggestions/yolsuggester</str>
<str name="storeDir">suggest_fuzzy_doc_expr_dict</str>
<str name="preserveSep">true</str>
<str name="preservePositionIncrements">true</str>
<str name="exactMatchFirst">true</str> 
<float name="threshold">0.005</float> 
<str name="buildOnStartup">false</str>
<str name="buildOnCommit">false</str>
</lst>


<lst name="suggester">
<str name="name">kapinosuggester</str>
<str name="lookupImpl">FuzzyLookupFactory</str>
<str name="dictionaryImpl">DocumentDictionaryFactory</str>
<str name="field">KAPI_NO</str>
<str name="suggestAnalyzerFieldType">textgen</str>
<str name="indexPath">suggestions/kapinosuggester</str>
<str name="storeDir">suggest_fuzzy_doc_expr_dict</str>
<str name="preserveSep">true</str>
<str name="preservePositionIncrements">true</str>
<str name="exactMatchFirst">true</str> 
<float name="threshold">0.005</float> 
<str name="buildOnStartup">false</str>
<str name="buildOnCommit">false</str>
</lst>

<lst name="suggester">
<str name="name">kapiadisuggester</str>
<str name="lookupImpl">FuzzyLookupFactory</str>
<str name="dictionaryImpl">DocumentDictionaryFactory</str>
<str name="field">KAPI_ADI</str>
<str name="suggestAnalyzerFieldType">textgen</str>
<str name="indexPath">suggestions/kapiadisuggester</str>
<str name="storeDir">suggest_fuzzy_doc_expr_dict</str>
<str name="preserveSep">true</str>
<str name="preservePositionIncrements">true</str>
<str name="exactMatchFirst">true</str> 
<float name="threshold">0.005</float> 
<str name="buildOnStartup">false</str>
<str name="buildOnCommit">false</str>
</lst>


</searchComponent>

<requestHandler class="solr.SearchHandler" name="/suggest">
<lst name="defaults">
<str name="spellcheck">true</str>
<str name="suggest">true</str>
<str name="suggest.dictionary">ilsuggester</str>
<str name="suggest.dictionary">ilcesuggester</str>
<str name="suggest.dictionary">mahallesuggester</str>
<str name="suggest.dictionary">sokaksuggester</str>
<str name="suggest.dictionary">caddesuggester</str>
<str name="suggest.dictionary">yolsuggester</str>
<str name="suggest.dictionary">kapinosuggester</str>
<str name="suggest.dictionary">kapiadisuggester</str>

<str name="spellcheck.count">10</str>

</lst>
<arr name="components">
<str>suggest</str>
</arr>
</requestHandler>


<field name="CADDE" type="textgen" omitNorms="true" omitTermFreqAndPositions="true" multiValued="true" indexed="true" stored="true"/>

<field name="ILCE_ADI" type="text_general" omitNorms="true" omitTermFreqAndPositions="true" multiValued="true" indexed="true" stored="true"/>

<field name="IL_ADI" type="text_general" omitNorms="true" omitTermFreqAndPositions="true" multiValued="true" indexed="true" stored="true"/>

<field name="KAPI_ADI" type="textgen" omitNorms="true" omitTermFreqAndPositions="true" multiValued="true" indexed="true" stored="true"/>

<field name="MAHALLE_ADI" type="textgen" omitNorms="true" omitTermFreqAndPositions="true" multiValued="true" indexed="true" stored="true"/>

<field name="SOKAK" type="textgen" omitNorms="true" omitTermFreqAndPositions="true" multiValued="true" indexed="true" stored="true"/>

<field name="YOL_ADI" type="textgen" omitNorms="true" omitTermFreqAndPositions="true" multiValued="true" indexed="true" stored="true"/>

<fieldType name="textgen" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
<analyzer type="index">
<tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
<filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="1" catenateNumbers="1" catenateAll="0" splitOnCaseChange="0"/>
<filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
</analyzer>
<analyzer type="query">
<tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
<filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
<filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory"
        ignoreCase="true"
        words="stopwords.txt"

        />
<filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="0" catenateNumbers="0" catenateAll="0" splitOnCaseChange="0"/>
<filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
</analyzer>
</fieldType>
```